# MvcContrib vs. MvcFutures

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, mvccontrib, asp.net-mvc-futures

What is the relation between MvcContrib and MvcFutures?

Looks like MvcFutures contains code that will be part of future ASP.NET MVC releases and MvcContrib is less official library which contains some features from community. Am I right?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you're right. MvcFutures does not accept community contributions, though the source is available for you to look at. MvcContrib is a collection of stuff people have found handy over the years, and you can add your own stuff too!